# How to use purrr with dplyr to filter list elements and export lists into Excel

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm fairly new to working with lists in R and have a quick question that also involes using `purrr`. Below are too small sample data frames as an example.

```
Client1 <- c("John","Chris","Yutaro","Dean","Andy")
Animals <- c("Cat","Cat","Dog","Rat","Bird")
Living <- c("House","Condo","Condo","Apartment","House")
Data1 <- data.frame(Client1,Animals,Living)

Client1 <- c("John","Chris","Yutaro","Dean","Andy")  
Animals2 <- c("Cat","Dog","Dog","Rat","Cat")
Living2 <- c("House","Apartment","Apartment","Family","Apartment")
Data2 <- data.frame(Client1,Animals2,Living2)
```

Bonus if you can include how to rename list elements at once instead of using the two lines below:

```
names(Data1)[1:3] <- c("Client","Animals","Living")
names(Data2)[1:3] <- c("Client","Animals","Living")
```

So next if I want to filter each data frame by `Animals` and then export each into an Excel spreadsheet by using the two lines of code below:

```
Data1 %>% filter(Animals=="Cat") %>% write.csv(.,file="Data1.csv")
Data2 %>% filter(Animals=="Cat") %>% write.csv(.,file="Data2.csv")
```

However, to be more efficient I can join both data frames into a `list` and use `purrr` to filter each at the same time.

```
DataList <- list(Data1,Data2)
DataList %>% map(~filter(.,Animals=="Cat"))
```

For the above code, I will use multiple `~filter` lines for each animal, so not sure if there's a more efficient way that will avoid writing many different lines of code while still using `purrr` and `dplyr`?

Also, how do I use `write.csv` with `purrr`. I can either export the list into one spreadsheet, but I'm not sure how to break up the list so that it exports properly. Also, I can export each list element into separate spreadsheets. It would be great to see a solution for both of these situations.

Comment: Is the final result you want a separate csv file for each kind of animal from each dataset?  In your real situation are your datasets this similar (i.e, they contain the same variables)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to write a separate file for each of the `Animals` of both the data frames:

```
DataList <- list(Data1, Data2)

library(purrr)


a <- DataList %>% map(., function(x) { 
        colnames(x) <- c("Client","Animals","Living")
        x
}) %>% map(., function(x) { 
        split(x, x$Animals)
}) %>% flatten(.)

names(a) <- paste0("Data", (1:length(a)))


lapply(1:length(a), function(x) write.csv(a[[x]], 
                                            file = paste0(names(a[x]), ".csv"),
                                            row.names = FALSE))
```

We first dump both the data frames in `DataList`, then rename the columns for both the data frames with the first `map`, then `split` both the data frames by `Animals`, and finally `flatten` the nested list.

I wish I could do this without breaking the chain, but I couldn't find another way.

From here, we first rename the elements of the list, then use `lapply` to loop over all the elements in the list and apply `write.csv` on each of them.

You mentioned `Excel` - you can just as easily replace `write.csv` with any of the functions for writing excel files from `R`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option, involving binding the two datasets together before re-splitting.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

DataList %>%
    map(~setNames(.x, c("Client","Animals","Living"))) %>%
    setNames(c("Data1", "Data2")) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
    split(list(.$id, .$Animals), drop = TRUE) %>%
    map(~select(.x, -id) %>% 
               write.csv(file = paste0(unique(.x$id), unique(.x$Animals), ".csv"),
                                row.names = FALSE))
```

The first `map` line shows how to rename the columns of all the datasets in a list at once via `setNames`.

```
DataList %>%
    map(~setNames(.x, c("Client","Animals","Living")))
```

I then set the names of the datasets in the list via `setNames`.  While stacking the datasets together into a single data.frame via dplyr's `bind_rows`, these names are added as a new column, `id`.

```
setNames(c("Data1", "Data2")) %>%
bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

The last step is to split the combined data.frame by `id` and `Animal` before writing each split into a separate csv file.  Information is pulled out of the dataset for naming the individual files by dataset and animal (this was the reason to name the elements of `DataList`).  I removed the `id` variable via `select` prior to writing the files, as it may be extraneous to your needs.

```
split(list(.$id, .$Animals), drop = TRUE) %>%
map(~select(.x, -id) %>% 
            write.csv(file = paste0(unique(.x$id), unique(.x$Animals), ".csv"),
                                row.names = FALSE))
```

This can be all be done without putting these into a single data.frame, but I had trouble with naming the files at the end.